# Getting "sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed" error when using airflow Variable inside "task_instance_mutation_hook"

Tags: airflow

We are using **"task_instance_mutation_hook**" to set queue for task. Queue_name we are getting from conf of restapi and before setting it to "**task_instance.queue**" we are trying to validate queue name from the available queues. Available list of queue is from airflow Variable.
If I am using **avaialble_queue = Variable.get("queues", deserialize_json=True)** then getting below error while if available_queue is hardcoded list like **avaialble_queue = ["q1", "q2"]** then working fine.
Error-
**File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3901, in _bulk_save_mappings
airflow-webserver-1  |     persistence._bulk_insert(
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 74, in _bulk_insert
airflow-webserver-1  |     connection = session_transaction.connection(base_mapper)
airflow-webserver-1  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 627, in connection
airflow-webserver-1  |     self._assert_active()
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 620, in _assert_active
airflow-webserver-1  |     raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg)
airflow-webserver-1  | sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed**

I don't understand why using variable is giving sqlalchemy error.